# How to change Rails app time zone setting based on user's input?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, timezone

I have a User model, which allow user to provide their own time zone. User can choose their own time zone using the `time_zone_select`. So we will store something like `Pacific Time (US & Canada)` in database.

My Rails 3 application default setting is using `Pacific Time (US & Canada)`. So all the time display is in this time zone.

May I change the time time display based on user time zone? For example, User A will see all the time displayed in his time zone `Central Time (US & Canada)`, and User B will see all the time in `London`.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `controllers/application.rb`

```
before_filter :set_user_time_zone

private

def set_user_time_zone
  Time.zone = current_user.time_zone if logged_in?
end
```

From [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/106-time-zones-in-rails-2-1)

Answer (score 2):

First you'll need to add a column to your users table, to keep the selected timezone for this user (user.timezone should be fine).
in the form, you'll need to use ActiveSupport's `#time_zone_select` to allow the user to select their desired timezone.

finally, you'll need a before filter in ApplicationController to set the current sessions's timezone to the user's specific timezone.

Here is a gist with the migration, partial view and application controller filter:

https://gist.github.com/eladmeidar/6121183